# I'm getting errors with `apt update` after updating Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: apt, updates

These are the error messages:

```
Err:1 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-security InRelease
  Could not resolve host: esm.ubuntu.com
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:4 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve host: esm.ubuntu.com
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/xenial-infra-security/InRelease  Could not resolve host: esm.ubuntu.com
W: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/xenial-infra-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve host: esm.ubuntu.com
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: First remove the 3rd party PPAs (probably won't work with 18.04) then run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` before trying again to do a release upgrade.

Comment: From your desktop, click on the "dots" i.e Show Applications then click on the icon for Additional Drivers and then click on the tab Other Software. This will show your dependencies and it would seem that several of them are no longer supported in 20/04 but you might not need them. Take a note of them and then delete them (the ones that bug out after the apt-update). Editing your sources.list file is a last resort, go GUI first.

Comment: Whoa. The OP is showing us *networking* errors: `Could not resolve host: esm.ubuntu.com` and `Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'`. These are not usually caused by PPAs nor by kernel modules.

Comment: Do other devices *on the same network* also have network problems? If so, it's likely to be a router or ISP issue, not Ubuntu. If only your Ubuntu system has these problems, then check NetworkManager to ensure that your DNS settings are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Step1. Check your Internet connection. If it is bad, switch to a local mirror. Also check whether your device is correctly set up to connect to the Internet.

Step2. remove all PPAs and try `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`

Step3. try manually changing `xenial` to `bionic` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and all files in `etc/apt/sources.d`, and then `sudo apt update`. I have not tried this before because this is the "debian way", but it should work. Though as a precaution you should back your files up.